# Why is AJAX in Rails 3 so hard? Or, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

None of the tutorials I seem do what I'm trying to do.  Very simply, I want a user to be able to submit a POST request to a controller (to "LIKE" a video) and have the controller respond back with a JSON object.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT** Because SO is messing the formatting up, here is a gist of my code too:
    https://gist.github.com/813503

### Here is my controller:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_ids

  respond_to :json, :js

  def videolink
    results = {}

    # check to see if the user has liked this videolink before
    if current_user
      liked = Like.video?(current_user, @vid_id)

      results["status"] = "OK"      
      results["liked"] = liked
    else
      results["status"] = "Error"
      results["message"] = "User not logged in"
    end

    respond_with( results.to_json ) 
  end


  def update
    results = {}

    if current_user
      results["status"] = "OK"  
    else
      results["status"] = "Error"
      results["message"] = "User not logged in"
    end

    respond_with( results.to_json )
  end


  private

  def get_ids
    @vid_id = params[:videolink_id]
  end

end
```

### Here is my JS file:

```
$("#likeVideo").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { game_id: game_id,   videolink_id: current_video["videolink"]["id"] },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/likes/" + game_id,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Success", data);
        }
    });     

    return false;
});
```

### My routes:

```
  resources :likes do
    collection do
      get "videolink"
    end

    member do
      post :update
    end
  end
```

### And here is the error I get:

## NoMethodError
    in LikesController#update

undefined method `{"status":"OK"}_url' for #<LikesController:0x0000010178be58>

Comment: Problem is inside of `respond_with( results.to_json )` it is not correct. :)

Comment: It works on the GET request.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: I don't understnd how your `likes/game_id` url works with `videolink` method? Where is show method? Your controller is messy. Why don't you use defult `PUT update`? You should read about REST convention

Comment: The controller wasn't complete.  Plus, I've cleaned it up.  I'm using a POST method because when a user "likes" a video, most of the time, that record will not exist.  If they were to like the same video twice, I prevent it.  Now a PUT would be better if they change their mind (hate video) but I didn't think the extra effort was worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send back custom JSON, Instead of respond_with(results.to_json)... just render the text

```
render :text=>results.to_json
```

The responds_with is a way for you to easily send back objects, with their location (url).  So that's why your error is telling you that that '_url' is invalid.

More info on responds_with, courtesy of http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering

> If another format was requested, (i.e.
>   :xml or :json)
>
> - If it was a GET request, invoke the :to_format method on the resource and
>     send that back
> - If the resource has validation errors, send back the errors in the
>     requested format with the
>     :unprocessable_entity status code
> - If it was a POST request, invoke the :to_format method on the resource
>     and send that back with the :created
>     status and the :location of the new
>     created resource
> - Else, send back the :ok response with no body

Comment: YES!  That's it.  Thanks for the education.  I knew I was stupid.  LOL